# Update storage schema on extension update in an event page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a method to change format of `localStorage` strings when the extension updates.

The question is more on *where* (in the [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) to execute the method.
The method MUST run at update or the whole extension will not work anymore.

Currently I put it here:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(runInfo) {
    if (runInfo.reason=="install") {

    }
    if (runInfo.reason=="update") {
        //HERE!!
    }
});
```

It executes fine on extension update, that's what I want.

*But it seems like if the extension is disabled when the update happens it will not run at all.*

Then when the extension is enabled again, the user will deem it to be a bug.

I was hoping there is a `chrome.runtime.onEnabled`, but there is no such event.

There is `chrome.management.onEnabled`, but I don't want the event page to wake up for every other extension's enabling/disabling.

Thought of putting the method to run every time the event page wakes, by putting it in `window.addEventListener("load", HERE);`, but I'm afraid running it every time might slow down the real work that the event page was triggered to do.

Any suggestions?
Any devs have any better way they are using now?

Comment: What's wrong with putting it in a background page? I think that would run every time it's updated/enabled/browser restarted..

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Its currently in the non-persistent background page (event page). Its just that at its current location it won't run when the extension is disabled and it doesn't pick up and run it after the extension is enabled.

Comment: It will if you put it outside the onInstalled? Then you can just check the version number to see if it's been updated by something like this http://siphon9.net/loune/2010/07/getting-the-version-number-of-your-own-chrome-extension/

Comment: I'm not sure I fully see your problem, but if that is helpful there was a comment in that last link that is much easier than the content itself `chrome.app.getDetails().version`

Comment: @judgeja That article was written 4 years ago. These days, you should get the extension version using `chrome.runtime.getManifest().version`.

Comment: But will running it every time slow down the actual task? Like on creating a new tab the event page will wake up to do the actual task but as the event page wakes it will need to check version number to see if update is needed then perform the actual task. Or are the event listeners all async and allow them to run parallel? Then could it cause more problems if the strings needed to work is not updated before the event listener does the actual task?

Comment: @RobW I thought it seemed a bit nasty for something simple but that was the best of my first 3 google results. bland.life when you make a new tab your background page won't do anything, only content scripts run then. Your background script is run when the extension starts, and then it continues to run in the background while your extension exists. It won't re-run the whole script on page loads.... When you say event page do you mean content script?

Comment: Edited your question a bit; comment: there is no need to wrap this code in `onload` event listener (might actually be bad, because it will execute after the callback).

Comment: @RobW Doesn't it seem strange to you that `onInstalled` is not called for enabling an extension? I believe this can be a feature request.

Comment: @judgeja The event page will wake up on tab creation if it listens to the `chrome.tabs.onCreated` event. Thats why I went on to talk about event listeners.

Comment: @Xan After the callback? As in the callback of the "load" event? I'm not very skilled in async Javascript :P Why is it bad?